# $.parseJSON breaking with double quotes

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Can someone pleas explain to me why json which contains a string with double quotes will break `$.parseJSON`?

This works:

```
[{"type":"message","content":{"user":"tomasa", "time":"1321722536", "text":"asdasdasd"}}]
```

This also works:

```
[{"type":"message","content":{"user":"tomasa", "time":"1321723267", "text":"&quot;"}}]
```

However this will cause [`$.jsonParse`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) to not return anything (I am assuming becuase it is a malformed json string:

```
[{"user":"tomasa", "time":"1321723278", "text":"&quot;&quot;"}}]
```

Comment: Please post an example of the JSON that is breaking the parser.

Comment: We need more information to give a meaningful answer. Nobody here can mind-read. You may want to look into the JSON specification (http://www.json.org/) though; JSON itself is fairly straightforward.

Comment: Can you provide an example please?

Comment: Sorry to all, I accidentally pressed enter when making my question (whoops) and hurried to make a semi acceptable one so I could edit it to the full question. my bad

Comment: I had the same issue validation shows NO error so i think its problem with jquery 1.7. For me solution whose remove switch: JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE in PHP  json_encode(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have an extra `}` at the end.

```
}}]
```

You should run troublesome JSON markup through http://jsonlint.com/

```
Parse error on line 6:
...&quot;&quot;"    }}]
---------------------^
Expecting ',', ']'
```

Comment: Ok thanks that is helpful. odd because there should be a { at ther beginning... but that at least tells me my php is causing issues

Comment: @Tomas, In future try using [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) to validate your JSON.

Comment: @Tomas: If you're saying that there should be a double `{` at the beginning just like the end, that would also be invalid.

Comment: Yeah sorry, basically the problem was I was storing json in sql. and I changed the php that generated the json half way thru... but I did check the first two (generated before I changed the php) in jsonlint and they validated... which is what led me to believe it was the double quotes.

Answer (score 5):

It's not the `"` or `&quot;` but the extraenous `}` you have:

```
[{"user":"tomasa", "time":"1321723278", "text":"&quot;&quot;"}}]
                                                              ^
```

Answer (score 3):

It crashes because of the double `}`.

```
>>> $.parseJSON('[{"user":"tomasa", "time":"1321723278", "text":"&quot;&quot;"}}]')
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected ',' or ']' after array element
(function(a,b){function cy(a){return f...h]&&f.event.trigger(c,d,b.handle.elem
```

But this works:

```
>>> $.parseJSON('[{"user":"tomasa", "time":"1321723278", "text":"&quot;&quot;"}]')
[Object { user="tomasa", time="1321723278", text="&quot;&quot;"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

$.parseJSON is looking for the name of the object in double quotes and the value of that object in single quotes. Is this what you are asking?

Answer (score 0):

Because the [JSON specification](http://json.org/) specifically states that `string` elements are defined as:

```
string
  ""
  " chars "
```

In other words, string values must be surrounded by double quotes in order to be valid JSON.

**Edited to add:**

My answer above is correct for the original question as it was posted a few seconds ago, which was basically "why does jQuery.parseJSON fail when double quotes aren't used", but then the OP modified the question to include an example that demonstrates his/her actually problem, which has nothing to do with the quotes at all.